# Pthread library causes program to Seg Fault at Exit

Tags: pthreads, cross-compiling

I am Cross Compiling PARSEC Benchmarks in Alpha, and several of the benchmarks seg fault when the program exits. I have narrowed the issue down to the Pthreads Library as I went ahead and ran a non-pthreads version and there was no seg fault. The programs get the correct results despite the seg fault, but this issue is unacceptable.

Some Info:
I am running these benchmarks in the M5 Simulator so I cannot dynamically link libaries, everything is statically link with -static.

Any Ideas on how to solve this?
Not sure whether I need to rebuild the pthreads library on my Alpha Cross Compiler or add additional flags.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post a stack trace at the segfault? It could be that you still have some threads running when you are exiting, which can lead to crashes. You should make sure that all threads are finished before exiting.